# Cloudspeech demo in voice AIY kit cryptography error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-aiy

I am running the **cloudspeech_demo.py** in my Google AIY voice kit.

I have also included the Google Cloud Speech to Text credentials

This is the error I am running into

```
INFO:root:Initializing for language en_GB...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/voice/cloudspeech_demo.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "examples/voice/cloudspeech_demo.py", line 46, in main
    client = CloudSpeechClient()
  File "/home/pi/AIY-projects-python/src/aiy/cloudspeech.py", line 62, in __init__
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_accout_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 209, in from_service_account_file
    filename, require=['client_email', 'token_uri'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 73, in from_filename
    return data, from_dict(data, require=require)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 54, in from_dict
    signer = crypt.RSASigner.from_service_account_info(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/crypt/base.py", line 115, in from_service_account_info
    info.get(_JSON_FILE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/crypt/_cryptography_rsa.py", line 148, in from_string
    key, password=None, backend=_BACKEND)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py", line 16, in load_pem_private_key
    return backend.load_pem_private_key(data, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1045, in load_pem_private_key
    password,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1271, in _load_key
    self._handle_key_loading_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1329, in _handle_key_loading_error
    raise ValueError("Could not deserialize key data.")
ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.
```

I am running the program on **Python3** and the cryptography version is **2.2**

Please help

Comment: Opening the service_account credentials file in notepad++ has changed something it seems.

Comment: Pushing the credentials file directly into the system without opening fixed the issue